# Renormalization group to predict the ground state of a Hamiltonian

Tags: renormalization, phase-transition, hamiltonian, ground-state

It is slightly difficult to phrase my question because I'm looking more of an entry point to something I know is a large field rather than a solution to a specific problem.

I occasionally see papers where the authors use some heavy numerical renormalization group methods to determine the ground state (i.e. superconducting, anti-ferromagnetic, etc.) of some rather complicated condensed matter Hamiltonian. I would like to learn more about these methods.

To make my question a bit more concrete, suppose that I have some non-interacting Hamiltonian (in 3D or 2D) written in the momentum space. Then I add some type of interaction term(s) parametrized by some set of coupling strengths. Now I want to know what is the ground state of this Hamiltonian? If I understand correctly, some renormalization group methods should give me the answer (perhaps after some approximations).

1. Can you suggest some specific flavour of renormalization group that can be applied to this type of problem (i.e. DMRG, FRG, etc.) along with some lecture notes, literature, etc.?
2. Using whatever method you suggest, what is the easiest non-trivial problem that you suggest I should try to program and solve?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say anything about the FRG but as far as I understand it the DMRG was very succssful in solving 1-d interacting problems but the extention to 2-d is very difficult and not yet very well advanced.

For an entry point into DMRG Noack and White have written a [pedagogical introduction](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjDiqHb2sHbAhUJUhQKHWhVDY8QFgg_MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbooks.google.com%2Fbooks%2Fabout%2FDensity_matrix_renormalization.html%3Fid%3DibjvAAAAMAAJ&usg=AOvVaw07isaak5vfnR9M6GyQER8K) where they show how to apply the method to the particle in a box (chapter 2).
Also there are some [lectures](https://youtu.be/4bCFXBYIdMY) by White which treat the same thing.